# bind a callback to the beginning and end of a method

Tags: php, oop, callback

I don't know if this is doable, as I could not find anything relevant by Googling it.

So basically what I have is a class with multiple methods, but I want to run a function right before and right after each one of them. So what I could do is:

```
class Test{
    function func1(){
        $this->before();

        //-- Some code here

        $this->after();
    }
    function func2(){
        $this->before();

        //-- Some code here

        $this->after();
    }
    private function before(){}
    private function after(){}
}
```

Is there a way for me to bind the `before()` and `after()` to all methods without having to call them the way I did.

Alternatively, what is the best way to go about this? My goal is extendability so with a function like this:

```
private function before(){
    $method = debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];
    $args = debug_backtrace()[1]['args'];
    if(function_exists("before_" . $method)){
        call_user_func_array("before_" . $method, $args);
    }
}
```

All I need to do in the future to extend the way func1 works is add a function with a name before_func1.

So am I going about this the right way? Or is there a better way to do this.